# Regular expression that replaces all numbers with NULL except for a few words (words can have numeric characters)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regexp-replace

Regular expression that replaces all numbers with an empty string except for a few words (words can have numeric characters) -- python
e.g.
words to be excluded: "cloud9" & "ec2"

```
cloud9 100 pesos dollars99 908908f098080 800 ec2
```

should be converted to:

```
cloud9  pesos dollars f  ec2
```

Tried this in python:

```
    \b(?!ignoreme23|43ignoreyou)\b\d+
```

Tests for above expression:

```
8 --> matches 8

8u9 --> matches 8 but not 9

100f --> matches 100

f100 --> does not match anything

999 --> matches all 9s

ignoreme23 --> ignores as required

ignoreme232323 --> ignores "ignoreme23" but does not match with the following "2323"

2434ignoreme23 --> matches 2334 ignores "ignoreme23" as required

23243ignoreyou --> matches 23243. Should only match 2324 and should ignore "43ignoreyou"

232 43ignoreyou --> matches 232 and ignores "43ignoreyou" as required

43ignoreyou --> ignores as required
```

Tried different regular expressions but can't seem to get around this.

Any insight?

Comment: Just an observation this here `(?!ignoreme23)\d+` is a subset of your regex, but the assertion will never  ever fail, so its useless. That's why it's not easy finding out what you mean. Also, you have `\b` surrounding your assertion, why .. it's redundant.

Comment: Basically your regex is exactly this `\b(?!43ignoreyou)\d+` Its unclear what the wordboundary is actually for though.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general expression `(?:(?:EXCLUDE1)|(?:EXCLUDE2)|[^\d\n])+` should address your problem. You can include as many non-capture groups of words or phrases as you would like.

It's a little unorthodox, but this regex matches everything *except* the digits you want to remove. At least for me, it was a lot easier to match the text I wanted to keep than the text I wanted to remove. In this case, I believe python will let you extract only the matched text, effectively deleting the digits.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/hcm48v/7/)

Comment: the solution you gave does exactly the opposite of the requirement.

Comment: @rohan is it possible that instead of selecting digits to remove, you select everything else to keep, and then transfer them to a new string? It seems that this might fit your requirement - if not, and it *has* to be done by selecting digits, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: hi Nick, how can this be written in a python program snippet? what function should be used?

Comment: @rohan `print(re.findall("(?:(?:ignoreme23)|(?:43ignoreyou)|(?:cloud9)|(?:ec2)|[^\d\n])+", line))` - see full snippet [here.](https://repl.it/repls/SkinnyJudiciousPerformance)

Comment: The expression is correct. But I can't figure how to write it in python to select based on the expression from an input string.

Comment: You're saying the user inputs "ignored" strings to be used in the regex? If so, see updated snippet [here.](https://repl.it/repls/SkinnyJudiciousPerformance) I trust you know how to get user input into an array, so I've omitted that from the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple regex

```
\d+[a-zA-Z]?\d+
```

To replace the numbers in the given text apply the following

```
re.sub(r'\d+[a-zA-Z]?\d+', '', giventext)
```

This function replaces the captured value from the giventext in accordance the regex expression \d+[a-zA-Z]?\d+ by the second argument of the function which is an empty string.

Output :-
cloud9  pesos dollars   ec2

Comment: it's close but the "f" was missed. The expected output is 'cloud9  pesos dollars f  ec2'